# Access Mongodb directly from client side

Tags: jquery, node.js, html, mongodb, express

I am new to mongodb and trying to access mongo db and retrieve the data in the client side [jquery/angular HTML5] for a web application. Will it be possible for me to use any dependencies or plugins in angular/jquery and access mongo db or is it mandatory to use node or express js and use API's from client to call the CRUD operations for mongo db? Please explain and suggest

Comment: You can ue mongoose but software recs are off topic for here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) to provide a REST API for mongodb and send requests via [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

As per the reply in the comments for this answer see http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api

Comment: Hi Bulkan. But that also requires some backend code like for CREST or Amid I need to use node. So, my query is without backend code, its not possible to directly access the mongo. Please suggest, if I am wrong

Comment: @vinod MongoDB doesn't provide a HTTP interface out of the box.

Comment: Ok. So, without server code difficult to connect to mongo right? Cool. THanks for the info.

Comment: @Bulkan yes it does, it has one inbuilt

Comment: @Sammaye can you provide a link to the documentation for the OP ?